# Find all bases such that $P$ in those bases ends with the decimal representation of $Q$

Tags: number-theory, number-systems, programming

> Given two numbers $P$ and $Q$ in decimal. Find all bases such that $P$ in those bases ends with the decimal representation of $Q$.

I was going to write a code for this problem. The idea in my mind was: I would convert $P$ to other bases and check if `P % pow(10, numberofdigits(B)) == B` is true (code is in C++ syntax).

Well, I can check for some finite number of bases but how do I know where (after what base) to stop checking. I got stuck here.

Comment: For the bases to check on, are they only those which are $\ge 10$, or also including any which are greater than the max. digit used in the decimal representation of $Q$ (e.g., if it only involves $0$ and $1$, then any base $\ge 2$ can be considered)? If bases which are larger than or equal to any of the digits of $Q$ are to be checked, how would you handle those larger digits of $Q$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan For more clarity, here is an example: For $P=71, Q=13$ answer should be $68 \text{ and } 4$

Comment: Thanks for the example; I take it you do support any base larger than the maximum digit of $Q$. I made a mistake in my earlier comment's last sentence. I actually wanted to ask if you supported any bases *smaller* than or equal to any of the digits of $Q$ and, if so, then how you would handle any larger digits of $Q$.

Comment: If you want to do it in code, you need the convert $Q$, not $P$. P is always staying the same number, $Q$ is the changing one (in your example, its "13" only in base 10, but represents "7" when in base 4 and "71" when in base 68. Also, you need to take the chose base to the power, not 10, as in your code.

Comment: For when to stop: The moment Q, when interpreted as base b, becomes bigger than P, you stop.

Comment: @Ingix Regarding the example: When $P=71,Q=13$ one of the answers is 68, meaning that when $P_{10}\rightarrow P_{68}$ we get $71\rightarrow 13$. So $P$ in base 68 ends with $Q$ in decimal. Therefore, I thought $P$ is changing while $Q$ is not...

Comment: There are two ways to solve the problem. 1) Make the computer calculate the digits of P in base b (need only the last ones, as many as Q has), then compare them with the digits of Q. 2) Calculate the value Q' of the number that Q becomes, when you take the decimal digts of Q, but interpret them as base b. Then you need make the computer check that P % (pow (b,<number of digits of Q>)) = Q'.
Your code seems to go in the direction of 2), so I answered that way. Your argements here seem to go in the direction of 1). Both direction are usable, but you can't really mix them,